# Does one need to clear immigration when crossing only international waters and returning to the same country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, sailing

More specifically, should I clear immigration when sailing from California to Hawaii?

Comment: I am pretty sure we already have a question covering this, but then for a return to the same harbor. Yes, you should report your arrival to the customs office and they will decide whether to investigate. For this distance I am pretty sure you will be searched.

Comment: You should report to Customs & Immigration... they may deem that you don't have to clear the process, but it's their decision to make.